# Unexpected results custom wp_query and $the_query->request;

Tags: wp-query

I have a problem with a WP query that I don't understand. If I query for the custom post type 'tribe_events' I get no results, while I know they exist. If I create a 'normal' sql query I do get the results I need. However, I wish to use the WP-way.

I've got this simple query:

```
<?php 
 $args = array(
 'post_type'     => 'tribe_events',
 'post_status'   => 'publish', 
 );

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   /*  Uncomment to see the resulting SQL to debug */
   echo $the_query->request; die();

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2>Test</h2>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see I have added $the_query->request; die(); But then I see a result that is strange:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_tec_occurrences 
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_tec_occurrences.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND 
( wp_tec_occurrences.post_id IS NOT NULL AND 
CAST(wp_tec_occurrences.end_date AS DATETIME) >= '2023-03-20 10:23:49' ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'tribe_events' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_tec_occurrences.occurrence_id 
ORDER BY wp_tec_occurrences.start_date ASC, wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I don't understand where this inner join with that table wp_tec_occurences is coming from? And the rest of that query?

If I only change the post_type to 'post' I do get the regular posts and a 'normal' query if I enable $the_query->request. See:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND 
wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I would expect this kind of query with post_type 'tribe_events' as well. Why is this different? Now it results in zero results, due to this query. What is the problem here?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `numberposts` isn't a valid argument for `WP_Query`, that's only for the `get_posts()` function. Use `post_count` instead. If `post_count` isn't specified, it defaults to 0. That doesn't explain why setting the `post_type` to `post` works as intended but it's a start I suppose. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837528/numberposts-showposts-posts-per-page-whats-the-difference).

Comment: @YourManDan You are right: not good, but unfortunately not the problem or solution ;) I have deleted this line in the code now. Thanks.

Comment: Might have to see your register custom post type code too. I'm not great with SQL so I can't help there, and the rest of your PHP looks fine to me. Note that the SQL for the custom post type request will be inherently longer and more complicated since it is only getting a subset of your posts, as opposed to all of them, so the query being more complicated isn't necessarily an issue.

Comment: From a quick research, the [`INNER JOIN` keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_join_inner.asp) selects records that have matching values in both tables. So I assume the SQL is saying to get the occurrences of `tribe_events` posts that appear in both the regular `wp_posts` table, and the `wp_tec_occurrences` table.

Comment: That's right: INNER JOIN does that. But why this table? Why not wp_postmeta? Why the date as I am not asking that in the query? I'm confused... ;)

Comment: Are you using Yoast SEO ? The Event Calendar chages his behaviour when I activate it, (not filling the wp_tec_occurence for new events). and I found this : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/event-calendar-crashes-wordpress-side-in-combination-with-yoast/